# Index out of bounds error in images displays

Tags: python, mnist, data-augmentation

let us consider following code :

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
X_train =X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],1,28,28)
X_test =X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],1,28,28)
X_train =X_train.astype('float32')
X_test =X_test.astype('float32')
datagen =ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True,featurewise_std_normalization=True)
datagen.fit(X_train)
for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=9):
# create a grid of 3x3 images
 for i in range(9):
     plt.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
     plt.imshow(X_batch[i].reshape(28, 28), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
# show the plot
plt.show()
break
```

it gives me following error :

```
IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6
```

it should be noted that previous code for generating mnist  dataset  works fine

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
(X_train,y_train),(X_test,y_test) =mnist.load_data()
for i in range(0, 9):
  plt.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
  plt.imshow(X_train[i], cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.show()
```

here is its result :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong indentation, `plt.show` and `break` should be at the level of the inner loop but you have them at the level of the outer loop.

```
for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=9):
  for i in range(9):
    plt.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
    plt.imshow(X_batch[i].reshape(28, 28), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
  # show the plot
  plt.show()
  break
```

Comment: could you please explain me in a few words what it relation  between indentation and out of index error in this case?

Comment: You expect to run the cycle for 9 times - (3x3) grid and then you need to break from that cycle otherwise your loop will continue and your logic will break somewhere along the line. Since `break` is incorrectly indented in your code, it will not be executed when it should (which is after the first pass of the outer cycle).

Comment: so what will be optimal for the second loop? should it be 9 or  some number which  makes relationship between number of times first loop will run ? for instance batch size or something like this

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. Do you want to show all the 50000 or so images that are in MNIST?

Comment: In that case, your loop is just fine. Outer loop has nothing to do with it, it just loops through all the images - that is why you need to break from it. You just need to make sure that the inner loop range and the number in `plt.subplot(330 + 1 + i)` are compatible.